# Extract grocery list out of free text

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am looking for a python library / algorithm / paper to extract a list of groceries out of free text.

For example:

> "One salad and two beers"

Should be converted to:

```
{'salad':1, 'beer': 2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/). You can call it from java (JWNL library), etc. Here is the suggestion: for each single word, check it's hypernym. For edibles at the top level of the hypernymy hierarchy you will find " food, nutrient". Which is probably what you want. Now to test this, query the word "beer" in the  [Online](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn) version. Click on the "S", and then click on "inherited hypernym ". You will find this somewhere in the hierarchy:

```
....
    S: (n) beverage, drink, drinkable, potable (any liquid suitable for drinking) "may I take your beverage order?"
        S: (n) food, nutrient (any substance that can be metabolized by an animal to give energy and build tissue) 
          ....
```

You can traverse this hierarchy using the programming language of your choice, etc. Once you flagged all the edibles, then you can catch the number , i.e. 2 in "2 beers", and you have all the information you need. Note that catching the numbers by itself can be a descent coding task! Hope it helps!

Comment: This would also be more robust with "now boil egg for three/3 minutes".

Answer (score 3):

```
In [1]: from word2number import w2n
In [2]: print w2n.word_to_num("One")
1
In [3]: print w2n.word_to_num("Two")
2
In [4]: print w2n.word_to_num("Thirty five")
35
```

You can convert to number with using this package and rest of things you can implement as your needs.

Installation of this package.

```
pip install word2number
```

**Update**

You can implement like this.

```
from word2number import w2n
result = {}
input = "One salad and two beers"
b = input.split()
for i in b:
    if type(w2n.word_to_num(i)) is int:
        result[b[b.index(i)+1]] = w2n.word_to_num(i)
```

**Result**

> {'beers': 2, 'salad': 1}

Comment: @hashcode55 That's why i mentioned above like OP have to change the algorithm on his needs.